# Getting 400 bad request while trying to use sms send rest API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, sms

**URL:**

```
https://{org-url}/sms/v1/messageContact/{message-key}/send
```

**Request Body:**

```json
{
    "Subscribers": [
        {
            "MobileNumber": "91##########",
            "SubscriberKey": "12z3x5v7",
            "Attributes": {
                "FirstName": "Trung",
                "LastName": "Doe"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Subscribe": "true",
    "Resubscribe": "true",
    "SendTime": "2020-07-22 20:00",
    "Override": "false",
    "keyword": "XXXX"
}
```

**Response Obtained: 400 Bad Request**

```json
{
    "errors": [
        "No valid subscribers were provided."
    ]
}
```

I'm getting this response back when I try to send an sms using sales force's REST API. I'm not sure what's going wrong, I followed the approach given in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSend.htm).

SMS is not getting triggered to India Mobile number, works for US mobile numbers.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE - please use the `{}` tool or triple backticks (```) to format your code blocks.

Comment: @DavidReed, Thanks, will keep in mind next time I post a question.

Comment: I was able to make this work by including the "keyword" parameter, but, now I'm getting n error saying "No valid subscribers were provided" if I give my India number, works for US numbers though. Any suggestions on what I should try?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include this information. On SFSE, comments are temporary and are used primarily to request clarification. Thank you!

Comment: Have you verified that your Mobile Studio is enabled to send to India? (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_change_enabled_countries.htm&type=5)

Answer (score -2):

Your mobile number seems to be in the wrong format. It must conform to ISO-3306-1 alpha-2 standards (as per the sfdc link you've shared). See here for the example codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes